# PHP 7.2 Warning count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, wordpress, parameters, count, warnings

i've a problem with Wordpress. This is the error message: PHP 7.2 Warning count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable /web/htdocs/www.firenzeflowershow.com/home/wp-content/themes/wpex-elegant/functions/meta/init.php on line 750

```
> elseif ( is_array( $meta_box['pages'] ) && count( $meta_box['pages']
> === 1  ))             $type = is_string( end( $meta_box['pages'] ) ) ? end( $meta_box['pages'] ) : false;
```

Comment: TYPO `elseif ( is_array( $meta_box['pages'] ) && count( $meta_box['pages'] ) === 1 )` your count does not have a closing `)` in the right place hence the content of the count has become a boolean

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I modify as you say but on line 751 then it gives me an error: "Syntacs error, unexpected T_VARIABLE"
How can I solve? thank you.
751 line: $type = is_string( end( $meta_box['pages'] ) ? end($meta_box['pages']) : false;

Answer (score 1):

The closing parenthesis of **count** is in the wrong position. You are actually passing a boolean to the function, because "**$meta_box['pages'] === 1**" will return true or false. Your code should be:

```
count($meta_box['pages']) === 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I modify as you say but on line 751 then it gives me an error: "Syntacs error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" How can I solve? thank you. 751 line: $type = is_string( end( $meta_box['pages'] ) ? end($meta_box['pages']) : false;

Answer (score 0):

Please try if this works:

```
elseif ( is_array( $meta_box['pages'] ) && count($meta_box['pages'])
>= 1  )
```

Comment: Please explain why this may work. Code-only answers are not a good thing

Comment: Thanks, I modified as you say but the error comes out: 
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$type' (T_VARIABLE) in /web/htdocs/www.firenzeflowershow.com/home/wp-content/themes/wpex-elegant/functions/meta/init.php on line 751"

Comment: Please check if you have an 'endif;'  statement. Otherwise please use { } for the elseif

Comment: ___Small Point___ `count($meta_box['pages']) > === 1` is also invalid syntax.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think they used it for cosmetic stuff here in this question only

Comment: We do not normally answer TYPO's they are normally no use to others and that is the prime function of SO, for a question and answer set to be useful to others

Comment: @RiggsFolly you're right :)

Comment: `>=`? Are you sure that is what they meant?

Comment: @Alessandro, please mark the correct answer as accepted so that it will be useful for others too.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
elseif ( is_array( $meta_box['pages'] ) && count( $meta_box['pages'] )
=== 1)             $type = is_string( end( $meta_box['pages'] ) ) ? end( $meta_box['pages'] ) : false;
```

Your code did not work because `=== 1` was inside the `count()` function call: `count($meta_box['pages'] === 1)`, and a comparison returns a `bool`. Here, I have changed it to `count($meta_box['pages']) === 1` which gets the number of elements in the array, and checks if it returns 1.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I modify as you say but on line 751 then it gives me an error: "Syntacs error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" How can I solve? thank you. 751 line: $type = is_string( end( $meta_box['pages'] ) ? end($meta_box['pages']) : false;

Comment: @Alessandro change it to `type = is_string( end( $meta_box['pages'] ) ) ? end($meta_box['pages']) : false; `

Comment: Thank you. I changed how you reported me but the error remains. Now it says: "Syntacs error, unexpected T_STRING"

Comment: @Alessandro which line?

Comment: 751 line: 

 type = is_string( end( $meta_box['pages'] ) ) ? end($meta_box['pages']) : false;

Comment: @Alessandro oh sorry, change it to `$type = is_string( end( $meta_box['pages'] ) ) ? end($meta_box['pages']) : false;`

Comment: I modify as you say, but now it reports me the "Syntacs error, unexpected T_VARIABLE"

Comment: @Alessandro you are changing something else. Show full code around it again please. Just copy and paste the code in my answer there. Don't change anything

Comment: line 750: elseif ( is_array( $meta_box['pages'] ) && count( $meta_box['pages']) === 1
 line 751:  $type = is_string( end( $meta_box['pages'] ) ) ? end($meta_box['pages']) : false;

Comment: Change line 750 to `elseif ( is_array( $meta_box['pages'] ) && count( $meta_box['pages']) === 1)`

Comment: MAGNIFICENT! Now everything works perfectly! Thank you, you were really fundamental and kind! Thanks thanks thanks!

Comment: @Alessandro :) Your welcome. Please consider accepting my answer by clicking the tick mark in my answer